# require_once path error in init.php when using composer

Tags: php, authentication, composer-php

Hi friends this is my folder structure

```
googleauth
    -app
       --classes
           ---googleauth.php
       --init.php
   -vendor
     --autoload.php
```

I have given the following path in init.php

```
 require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
 require_once 'classes/GoogleAuth.php';
```

then the error is shown as

```
Warning: require_once(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such          
file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\googleauth\app\init.php on     
line 5
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php'      
(include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in     
C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\googleauth\app\init.php on line 5
```

So how can I resolve it by giving the correct path for the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `'../vendor/autoload.php'` because the path is from the file you running it in.

Comment: also note always use correct case for the filenames `GoogleAuth` vs `googleauth`. your app may work on windows, but if sometime you move code to non windows platform it will break

Answer (score 0):

User below code

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';   // ".." for parent directory
require_once './classes/GoogleAuth.php'; // "." for same dir.

if you are using linux (it is case sensitive), then file name will be the same. like if your file name is "googleauth.php" then you can't use it as "GoogleAuth.php".